# *ngFor not working with templateUrl when compiling files to a dist folder

Tags: angular

I am using angular2.0.0-rc4 . I have setup up gulp tasks to push all the required files to a dist folder for continuous integration. Doing this however seems to break `*ngFor` when using the `templateUrl` in the component. The angular is very simple

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  names:string[];
  constructor(){
     this.names=['name1','name2','name3']
  }
 }
```

**Html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let name of names">{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I get the error
`Can't bind to 'ngforOf' since it isn't a known native property`

For the /dist i am passing in the libraries that i think i need in a gulp task

```
 return gulp.src([
        'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'rxjs/**',
        'zone.js/dist/**',
        '@angular/**',
        'core-js/**'
    ], { cwd: 'node_modules/**' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/lib'));
```

I then change the map in the systemjs.config.js

```
 var map = {
   'app': 'app', // 'dist',
   '@angular': 'lib/@angular',
   'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'lib/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
   'rxjs': 'lib/rxjs'
 };
```

On the index.html i am also calling the libraries from the newly created /dist/lib folder like so

```
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="lib/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

If i use the standard "way" by calling from the node_modules folder and putting the index.html on the root on the site then everything works fine. just not when i use it in a sub folder (/dist)

Not too sure what i am doing wrong here, any suggestions for a solution or even a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing nothing wrong, Angular 2 doesn't support relative path by default.

[Angular 2 tutorial print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwXoM.png)

This can be found in link:

> We specify the path all the way back to the application root — app/ in this case — because Angular doesn't support relative paths by default. We can switch to component-relative paths if we prefer.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html

Comment: well that sucks ... the more i am using this framework the more i am seriously considering moving to aurelia

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem than you. I'm using angular2.0.0-rc4 with meteorjs and I put the templateUrl in my Component... same error!!
I "resolve" the problem put the entire html in template, instead templateUrl.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template : `<body>
  <app>
    You are so crazy, {{name}}!!

   <div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let party of parties">
          {{party.name}}
          <p>{{party.description}}</p>
          <p>{{party.location}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </app>
</body>` 
})
```

I Hope this be fixed.

Comment: That defeats the point of abstracting the html from the javascript. This is not a solution. It just highlights the stupidity that is angular2 and its over engineered mess that it is , in much the same way everyone though it was  a bad idea when microsoft was using it with webforms.